# How to change an Android Library to a Java Library

Tags: android, android-library

I have an Android library, but it has no activities or xml pages so it should actually be a Java Library, how do I convert it and should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it has no activities or xml pages so it should actually be a Java Library

It does not mean that you can "convert" it. In a nutshell every Android library **is** a Java library which relies on Android SDK.

Comment: Yeh sorry my understanding of this is pretty poor.  When you start a project you can choose android library or java library.  I chose android library, however my library has no "screens", although it does have other android things like local storage and 3rd party libraries like reterofit.  

Should it be a java library or an android library and does it matter?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by `local storage`. If you use `Context` and other Android-related operations to access the storage - then you have to keep using Android library. Otherwise you might use Java library or just continue using Android library.

Answer (score 0):

The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project. .aar file 
 consists a JAR file and some resource files. You can convert it
 as .jar file using this steps

1) Copy the .aar file in a separate folder and Rename the .aar file to .zip file using 
 any winrar or zip Extractor software.

2) Now you will get a .zip file. Right click on the .zip file and select "Extract files". 
 Will get a folder which contains "classes.jar, resource, manifest, R.java,
 proguard(optional), libs(optional), assets(optional)".

3) Rename the classes.jar file as yourjarfilename.jar and use this in your project.